# How can I get a block to display only on node view in Drupal 6

Tags: 6, nodes

I have a block that I need displayed only on the main page of a node.

I can get it to display on node/1/view by putting node/*/view in the conditions, but that only works if view is in the URL. I want it to show whether I go to node/1/view or node/1, but NOTHING else. If I try node/* it shows it for every node page, not just node/1. I also tried node/*/ but that didn't work at all as it appears the ending slash is being removed.

Comment: I think I'm missing something here... what are you calling the "main page of a node"?

Answer (score 1):

In that case you need to to have `node/*/view` and `node/*` on separate lines.

Unless the node that users are customizing are a specific node type, then you should use the php code to check for a certain node type, regardless of node id or url.

Comment: I tried that, node/* adds it to every page in the node, not just the main one.

Comment: So the node id is not fixed, and the node that the user will be customizing is not a specific content type?  Explain your whole scenario in as best detail as possible to we can answer correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the PHP method and do something like this:

```
<?php

$path=$_GET['q'];
$elements=explode('/',$path);
$count=count($elements);

if (($count==2 && $element[0]=='node' && is_numeric($elements[1]) ||
    ($count==3 && $element[0]=='node' && is_numeric($elements[1] && $element[2]=='view')) {
    return TRUE;
}

return FALSE;

?>
```

If you put this in the "Show block on specific pages/ Show if the following PHP code returns TRUE (PHP-mode, experts only)" part of the block admin page, you should be all set (barring any horrible typos or brainfades on my part :)

Comment: Although I would most certainly use the arg(0), arg(1) and arg(2) instead of an $elements variable and you're missing a few parenthesis in that example... but that's pretty much the only way because node/* will otherwise give you all the paths that start with node/...

Comment: The arg() function does the $_GET explosion internally, so that's pretty much stylistic, but yes, I did miss a paren to close the second is_numeric() :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I've missed the point but you can enter multiple values in that field, one per line. So have `node/1` and `node/1/view` on separate lines.

Comment: That's not going to work though, I need it to be automatic as users will be signing up and getting a node page to customize. There will be thousands of them, and more added every day.

Comment: The 1 in the above value is the userid?

Comment: No, the 1 in the above code would be the node id.

Comment: users have a node reference to a particular node? What node page are they customising?